# Android Studio Comment Formatting

Tags: android, android-studio, code-formatting

I want to **custom format the single line commenting** of the Android studio as I always wanted my code should look good.

When i do **cmd + /** it comments the code as

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//        var a=10
}
```

But instead of the above I want comments right at the start of code as

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //var a=10
}
```

When the code goes inside of 2-3 nested if comments at start won't look good as below

```
if(true) {
    if(true) {
        if(true) {
            if(true) {
                if(true) {
//                            var a=10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want **it should look like below** :

```
if(true) {
    if(true) {
        if(true) {
            if(true) {
                if(true) {
                    //var a=10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 8):

You just go:

Settings:

Then in the pane of the settings: 
**Settings-> editor > code style > Java**

Tab tab: **code generation**.

Here you will find the range of settings: comment code

- Line comment at first column
- Block comment at first column

Just uncheck them both.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to

> **File --> Settings --> Code Style --> Java --> Wrapping and Braces tab and uncheck "Comment at first column"**

[image]

Comment: @Nikhilesh Patve is your issue solved?

Comment: No not worked it is showing in preview after unchecking it will work as i am expecting but in editor it not working as expected

Comment: it will work in editor have you tried reformatting after this unchecked ?@NikhileshPatve

Comment: Yes obviously but in preview it is showing me

Comment: yes, it will work defenately.working on myside@NikhileshPatve

Comment: @NikhileshPatve //if it showing in preview than it should be working

Comment: amit : Can you please check the video i have created http://niks.96.lt/video/demo.mov it is not working on my mac.FIY - I am using android studio 3.0

Comment: @NikhileshPatve try using restarting android studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158211/discussion-between-nikhilesh-patve-and-amit-vaghela).

Comment: @NikhileshPatve did you get any solution ?

Comment: No still working manually.

Comment: this is only solution found and is working@NikhileshPatve

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat your code using `Control + Alt + L` on Windows/Linux or using `Command + Option + L` on Mac after writing your code.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html)